# Lenovo Ideapad battery limit

Tags: power-management, lenovo, battery, ideapad

I have an Ideapad Y400 running Ubuntu 13.10.  It previously ran Windows 8, and had a Lenovo utility to limit the battery charge to 60%.  Now that I've installed Ubuntu, of course, the utility is gone.  Is there a way I can limit the charge level?

Tp_smapi works for this purpose for Thinkpads, but I have an Ideapad, which apparently isn't supported.

Answer (score 5):

this post is quite old but I stumbled over it when I was searching for a solution setting battery charge levels for my Lenovo Ideapad U430 under Ubuntu. I actually got this working thanks to this [thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/ideapad-linux-acpi-driver-for-power-managment/td-p/2267447) and want to share my solution. 
I installed acpi-call. Following commands are setting the charge level:

```
# 100%
echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.VPC0.SBMC 5' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/call
# 50%-60%
echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.VPC0.SBMC 3' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/call
```

Answer (score 2):

this could be due to forgetting conservation mode on in the Lenovo vintage software in windows

to manage conservation mode from linux there is a gnome extension that does the monitoring and switching (like Lenovo vintage on windows)

[click here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode)

there is a also a manual method

::::::::: Conservative mode commands ::::::::

from terminal

```
sudo su
```

*write password*

**reading the current status:**

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**enable Conservation mode:**

```
echo 1  >  /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**disable conservation mode:**

```
echo 0  > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, on my Ideapad L340 with Debian Buster (kernel 4.19) I can just do:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

(From [Problem with Lenovo battery threshold](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038471/problem-with-lenovo-battery-threshold/1093935#1093935))

Answer (score 0):

Install laptop-mode-tools on your pc.It will increases the battery discharging time.

```
sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools
```

After that restart your pc.

Comment: That alone didn't work for me. Do I have to do something with the configuration file?