# Problem with Lenovo battery threshold

Tags: lenovo, battery, ideapad

I recently installed Linux on my Lenovo Ideapad 320, but I forgot to disable conservation mode from Lenovo vantage with Windows 10. The problem is that now my PC doesn't charge over 60%. I already tried with tlp but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I return to default thresholds (100%)?

Comment: The simple solution would be to reboot Windows 10 and set the threshold to 100%. Did you delete Windows 10? You should always keep it (but reduce it's size) so you can install new drivers, boot into it if Ubuntu breaks and as you point out to change battery charge threshold.

Comment: That's what I've done and now it finally charge at full. I thought that the conservation mode will write on the os, so changing it the mode will turn off automatically but it's not.  Thank you a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I've changed the comment into an answer so that others know it solves the problem. You can click the grey check mark next to the answer if it's acceptable. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The battery *conservation mode* is enabled with:

```
$ echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.VPC0.SBMC 3' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/call
```

It can be disable with:

```
$ echo '\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.VPC0.SBMC 5' | sudo tee /proc/acpi/call
```

On Debian/Ubuntu you should install the package `acpi-call-dkms`

(Credits: [ArchLinux wiki - Lenovo IdeaPad 720s](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_720s#Battery_Conservation_Mode))

The just mentioned wiki page refers to the IdeaPad 720s, on my IdeaPad 320 I've double check on the BIOS DSDT table and it seems to be the same. Browsing the web, I've found a case where the proper code to enable it was 4 (instead of 3) but 5 was used to disable it in any case.

**Edit Edit Edit**

The battery conservation mode is now exposed via the kernel module `ideapad-laptop`, so just load the module and then use:

```
# to read the current status
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode

# to enable
echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode

# to disable
echo 0 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Answer (score 2):

to manage conservation mode from linux there is a gnome extension that does the monitoring and switching (like Lenovo vintage on windows)

[click here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode)

there is a also a manual method

::::::::: Conservative mode commands ::::::::

from terminal

```
sudo su
```

*write password*

**reading the current status:**

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**enable Conservation mode:**

```
echo 1  >  /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**disable conservation mode:**

```
echo 0  > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Comment: Thank you!Thank you! I was search this for months. This answer should be more accessible to anybody who is searching. This works for all Ideapads and Legions.

Comment: And this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution would be to reboot Windows 10 and set the threshold to 100%.

You should always keep Windows installed (but reduce it's size) so you can install new drivers, boot into it if Ubuntu breaks and as you point out to change battery charge threshold.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks how to *disable* conservation mode.  My issue was the opposite:  I wanted to *activate* conservation mode.  After booting I was always having 0 and going to 100% in the battery charge.

If you run `cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode`,
you will get `1` or `0` as the output.  `1` means `conservation_mode` is activated.  `0` means it's disabled.

To enable conservation mode, my solution was to edit this file:

```
sudo gedit /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

and change `1` to `0`.

While this solved my problem, I still could not figure out how to make the change permanent in Windows or Ubuntu.