# Lenovo Battery Stuck

Tags: lenovo, battery, ideapad

After I used my computer with Windows 10 on it, I decided to switch it to Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.1) But I forgot my computer at conservation mode in Lenovo vantage. I saw some solutions suggesting resetting bios but I primarily use my PC plugged in and still want to be able to switch to conservation mode. Is there an easier way to switch between 60% charge threshold and %100?

P.S: I tried solutions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093935) answer. They did not work. I got a `tee: /proc/acpi/call: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure the problem is the conservation mode in the Lenovo Vintage.

if you are using Ubuntu then there is a gnome extension,[charging-mode](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode/) that allows you to monitor and switch between different charging modes. it worked for me on Lenovo Legion. I am the creator of this extension.

[click here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4129/charging-mode)

if you are using something else there is a manual method

::::::::: Conservative mode commands ::::::::

from terminal

```
sudo su
```

*write password*

**reading the current status:**

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**enable Conservation mode:**

```
echo 1  >  /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

**disable conservation mode:**

```
echo 0  > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
```

Comment: please [edit] this and mention if you are the creator of the extension